# unix shell scripting rename the files while comparing with different names

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have files on my directory /home/export few files.Now i would like to rename the files on my directory /home/export based on a txt file (which i have saved in /home/content.txt).I would like to compare the two and rename my files in the directory /home/export.
for example in my directory /home/export there is files hu12manrtty and in my content.txt the file name is hu12manrtty34mysqljpgno5678.
Now if first 10 chars are matching then i would like to rename my files present in /home/export.
for example the new name for file present in /home/export  hu12manrtty would be hu12manrtty34mysqljpgno5678

---

Thank you for your reply.I a txt file on path /home/content.txt which contains one column of names example :41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8git.pnggreat learning
41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8git.pnggreat learning
41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8git.pnggreat learning
d92791e8be6f5a40f5df7a4f9b1c3bd0e4126919mysql.txtbalaji balaji .The second path /home/export few files d92791e8be6f5a40f5df7a4f9b1c3bd0e4126919 ,41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8 so on.Now copmaring the two and then saving the file as 41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8git.pnggreat learning,41ef9a6d8f45839e32380e0312a25421c7b2dec8git.pnggreat learning and so on But the character should match i mean the first 10 character at leaset then only it should rename.Thanks. i have been trying but not working for me        for i in $(cat /home/contenthash1.txt);
do
sudo find /var -name $i | grep -oP "^[[:alnum:]]{10}" /home/contenthash1.txt; -exec mv /home/filedirmoodle/ ;
done
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Why not loop over the names in `content.txt` and use POSIX `expr substr "$var" 1 10` to isolate the 1st 10 characters of what was read from the file and then check if the file exists in the `export` directory. If it does move the existing file to the new name (in bash you could use a simple *parameter expansion*). `awk` provides another simple approach -- though you haven't tagged the question that way. Show us what you have tried and any output or errors you receive.

Comment: Also did you mean 11-characters? Otherwise there is the potential you will have both `export/hu12manrtty` and `export/hu12manrttz` that would both match  based on the first 10 characters.